# axios post request error with 422 (Unprocessable Entity) from react

Tags: reactjs, sqlalchemy, axios, fastapi

from FastAPI & sqlalchemy

```
@app.post("/users")
    def create_users(email: str, pwd: str, first_name: str, last_name: str, phone_number: str, city: str):
        user = UserTable()
        user.email = email
        user.pwd = pwd
        user.first_name = first_name
        user.last_name = last_name
        user.phone_number = phone_number
        user.city = city
    

        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
    
        return f"{email} created..."
```

React axios.post request

```
const addUserHandler =  () => {
        console.log(email, pwd, first_name, last_name, phone_number, city);
        axios
            .post('http://localhost:8000/users', {
                email: email,
                pwd: pwd,
                first_name: first_name,
                last_name: last_name,
                phone_number: phone_number,
                city: city,
            })
            .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.response.data);
            });
        console.log(city);
    };
```

below is error code

```
xhr.js:177 POST http://localhost:8000/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
App.js:37 
{detail: Array(6)}
detail: Array(6)
0: {loc: Array(2), msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
1: {loc: Array(2), msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
2: {loc: Array(2), msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
3: {loc: Array(2), msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
4: {loc: Array(2), msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
5: {loc: Array(2), msg: "field required", type: "value_error.missing"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

code is from react & axios and i got 422 error and couldnt post. i did check variables(useState) had a each string. but error still shows "field required" and "value_error.missing". how can i fix ths?

thaks for any reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are expecting ["query params"](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) in the url (fastapi), not a json body.

So,

```
@app.post("/users")
    def create_users(email: str, pwd: str, first_name: str, last_name: str, phone_number: str, city: str):
```

is expecting something like

```
/users?email=a&pwd=b&first_name=c...
```

Try working with [Pydantic models](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/), that way fastapi will be waiting a body in the request.

Comment: Thank you so much! So you mean that in fastapi i have to use pydantic model(json) instead of query params such as (email : str ..) ? Thanks for feedback i will deepdive more!

Comment: Yes, you should use models when you are trying to create/update a resource (POST, PUT, PATCH)

Comment: Thank you so so much!