# Error of send data to blockchain application in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have blockchain application and created Reactjs interface to send data from user to application but when i enter data and try send it get error as follow , any one can help me?

The error is :

XHR POST http://localhost:3000/api/MedicalRecord

[HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity 19ms]

**The App.js file as follow**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PostForm from './PostForm'

  function App() {
   return (

  <div className="App">
     <PostForm></PostForm>
     </div>
);
   
  }

 export default App;
```

**The PostForm.js file as follow**

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class PostRecords extends Component {

  
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    
     this.state = {
         record_Id: "",
         patient: "",
         doctor: "",
         description: "",
         prescription: ""
  
     }
  }
  handleChange =(e) =>{
     this.setState({
         [e.target.name]: e.target.value
     })
 }
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.post('http://localhost:3000/api/MedicalRecord')
    .then(response =>{
        console.log(response)
    })

 }
   

render() {
    const {record_id, patient, doctor, description, prescription} = this.state
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div>
                <label>record_id :</label>
               <input
                type='text' 
                name ='record_id'
                value={record_id}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>patient :</label>
               <input
                type='text' 
                name ='patient' 
                value={patient}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>doctor :</label>
               <input
                type='text' 
                name ='doctor' 
                value={doctor}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>description :</label>
               <input
                type='text' 
                name ='description' 
                value={description}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>prescription :</label>
               <input
                type='text' 
                name ='prescription' 
                value={prescription}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                ></input>
            </div>
            <button type='submit'>Submit Now</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
} 
export default PostRecords
```

Comment: It looks like you are sending the post request without any data and just only the URL. Please try to pass the data you want to pass as the second argument. If you don't want to pass any data, please check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379986/axios-post-request-error-with-422-unprocessable-entity-from-react)

Comment: Thanks  @VijayKumar for response ... I sent data but still same error